# Setting a household name field based on records in the household

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to calculate and set a HouseholdName field on an `Entity` table for all households consisting of 2 people. I am using SQL Server 2012 and the schema I must work with is:

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
   EID INT, --PK
   PID INT, --FK to Person.[Person ID]
   HouseholdID VARCHAR(50), 
   HouseholdName VARCHAR(300)
);

CREATE TABLE Person
(
   [Person ID] INT, 
   FirstName   VARCHAR(30), 
   LastName    VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (1,1,'HH1',NULL);
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (2,2,'HH1',NULL);
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (3,3,'HH2',NULL);
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (4,4,'HH2',NULL);
INSERT INTO Entity VALUES (5,5,'HH3',NULL);

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1,'Jane', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2,'Joe',  'Doe');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (3,'Sara', 'Dillin');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (4,'Bill', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (5,'Ted',  'Loner');
```

The logic for calculating the household name is this:
If both last names are the same such as for HouseholdID `HH1` the household name should be 'Jane & Joe Doe'. If last names differ such as in `HH2` it should be in the format 'Sara Dillin & Bill Smith'

I can identify the people and get them in order like so:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,HouseholdID
FROM Entity e
JOIN Person p ON p.[Person ID]=e.[PID]
WHERE HouseholdID IN  --HHs of 2 people
(
   SELECT DISTINCT HouseholdID
   FROM Entity e
   JOIN Person p ON p.[Person ID]=e.[PID]
   GROUP BY HouseholdID HAVING COUNT(*)=2
)
ORDER BY HouseholdID
```

But I'm stuck past that. From a procedural language like C# I know how to solve this, but it's slow. I'd love to be able to do it in a faster SQL way.

Comment: +1 for DDL and sample data. It would be great if more people did this.

Comment: You may google for ["concatenate rows"](http://www.google.de/search?q=concatenate+rows+sql). That's what your question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have changed field names slightly to make it easier to code. The following query will get you what you want:

```
SELECT 
  e1.HouseholdID,
  CASE WHEN p2.LastName =  p1.LastName THEN  p1.FirstName + ' & ' + p2.FirstName + ' ' + p2.LastName
       ELSE p1.FirstName + ' ' + p1.LastName + ' & ' + p2.FirstName + ' ' + p2.LastName END AS HouseholdName,
  p1.FirstName,
  p1.LastName,
  p2.FirstName as p2FirstName,
  p2.LastName as p2LastName
FROM 
 Person p1 
 INNER JOIN Entity e1 ON 
   p1.id = e1.PID
 LEFT JOIN Entity e2 
   ON e1.HouseholdID = e2.HouseholdID AND e1.id < e2.id
 LEFT JOIN Person p2
   ON e2.PID = p2.id
WHERE e2.ID IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT * FROM Entity e3 
      WHERE e1.HouseholdID = e3.HouseholdID
      AND NOT e3.id IN (e1.id, ISNULL(e2.id, 0))
    )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8dd9/15

Comment: I hadn't thought of joining the same table multiple times. That will give me what I need to make it work. Thank you!